# What topics are not allowed on Money?

Tags: discussion, top-7, allowed-topics

What are the allowed topics for this site?  According to the [FAQ](https://money.stackexchange.com/faq)

> Personal Finance and Money - Stack Exchange is for people who want to be financially literate, find ways to save money, minimize taxes, invest wisely, plan for retirement, etc. Also for financially-savvy amateurs, DIY-investors & personal finance pros.

The top 5 [on topic questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721?tab=ontopic&phase=definition#tab-top) from definition were:

- How do you determine how large your Emergency Fund should be?
- What's the difference between a traditional IRA and a Roth IRA?
- I'm way over budget on my grocery bills. What are some ways for me to cut costs?
- How can I calculate the future benefit of maxing out contributions to my 401k account, so I can weigh it against my need for liquidity today?
- What can I replace Microsoft Money with, now that MS has abandoned it?

The top 5 [off topic questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721?tab=offtopic&phase=definition#tab-top) from definition were:

- Where can I find the lowest prices on [electronics/furniture/etc.]?
- I just bought Apple stock! Isn't a great buy at $260? I hear it's going to $300! Shouldn't you buy it now?
- How can I make money on eBay?
- What's the biggest mistake you have made in trading stock?
- In a recession, should the Federal Reserve intervene? If so, what measures are appropriate?

***Can we create some better definition around exactly what type of questions should be closed?***

---

**Related:**

> [general advice on getting good prices](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/general-advice-on-getting-good-prices)

Comment: I thought "What can I replace Microsoft Money with, now that MS has abandoned it?" count as recommendation? http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/848/what-counts-as-recomendation