# Are questions along the lines of "How do I save on X?" acceptable?

Tags: discussion, faq, questions

After some contemplation and discussion regrading questions like "Where can I get deals on X?" [in this meta question](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/useful-but-subjective-questions-along-the-lines-of-where-can-i-get-deals-on-x), I have another.

What about questions of the form "How can I save money on X?"  I actually thought of that as I was writing out the meta question linked above.  Would that be a suitable form for the question?  Though such questions could also be contentious/subjective, I do think they are of some value.  Certainly more value than "Where can I get deals on X?"

---

> **Related:** [general advice on getting good prices](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/general-advice-on-getting-good-prices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"How can I save money on ..." sounds good to me.     The answers to that type of question will be things like:

- Buy X used.
- See if you can rent Y instead of purchasing.
- Ask for a specific kind of discount.
- Buy A instead of B.

The answers are not specific in time and should age well.   This is more like the [airline question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2580/when-is-the-best-time-to-buy-airline-tickets) discussed in the [general advice on getting good prices](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/general-advice-on-getting-good-prices) meta question than the [textbook question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/what-are-some-sites-that-offer-decent-deals-on-college-textbooks) discussed in [Useful, but subjective questions along the lines of: Where can I get deals on X?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/useful-but-subjective-questions-along-the-lines-of-where-can-i-get-deals-on-x).

Comment: personal finance is about saving and making money.  I think save on questions are good ideas here.